# What event should I use for closing client websocket in Electron application?

Tags: javascript, websocket, electron, connection, dom-events

I have Electron application. There is websocket connection between server and client side of electron app (another words, I use `websocket` on `index.html`).

I need to close websocket connection, when user closes the application. What event should I use for it?

There is `mainWindow.on('closed', () => { });` but I have no access to browser code at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use IPC (Internal Process Communication). In the electron framework, there are two processes:

- Main (The main process creates web pages by creating BrowserWindow instances.)
- Renderer (The main process manages all web pages and their corresponding renderer processes)

These two can communicate together using IPC. For more details see [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer)